# WPF - synchronous animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, synchronous

I have something this:

```
scaleTransform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, shrinkAnimation);
scaleTransform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, shrinkAnimation);
MyDialog.Show();
```

The animations run correctly in parallel (x and y shrink together), but because `BeginAnimation` is an asynchronous call, the `Show()` method gets executed while the animation is still running (suppose `shrinkAnimation` runs for 1 second).

How can I wait for animations to complete before calling `Show()`?

Thanks!

Comment: A solution easier than Mike's would be to replace my last line of code with: 
shrinkAnimation.Completed += delegate { MyDialog.Show(); };

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Storyboard`, which has a completed event, instead of that `BeginAnimation` method. Here's an example, setting opacity, but it's the same concept:

```
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(0.0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)));

Storyboard board = new Storyboard();
board.Children.Add(animation);

Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, MyButton);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("(Opacity)"));

board.Completed += delegate
{
    MessageBox.Show("DONE!");
};

board.Begin();
```